# restoring state in a presenter with MVP

Tags: android, mvp

https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf says to restore state in the model instead of the presenter.  What if I have a very simple "model", say a binary toggle that updates a textview to be on or off?  Creating a model Toggle class that has a single string value seems like overkill.

Another option is to pass the bundle from my Activity into a corresponding method in my presenter inside onSaveInstanceState and restore it similarly with onCreate.  *But the article also says that we should avoid having android dependencies in the presenter*.

Finally I tried using Icepick but this did not work:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
    (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
    presenter.onCreate();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    presenter.onButtonClicked();
}

@Override
public void updateState(String state) {
    tv.setText(state);
}
```

MainPresenter.java

```
    public class MainPresenter {

    private MainView mainView;
    @State String toggle;

    @Inject
    public MainPresenter(MainView mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
    }

    void onCreate() {
        mainView.updateState(toggle);
    }

    void onButtonClicked() {
        mainView.updateState(toggle.equals("on") ? "off" : "on");
    }
}
```

What are my options?  If I have to use the model approach can I see an example of this for my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotation processing to maintain the state, it won't automatically populate data into your presenter without `Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState)` which you can't call in the presenter.

`@State String toggle;`

This line should be present in the activity. Have a method in your presenter to request data by toggle. Something like this:

```
@State String toggle = "off"; //default value

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
presenter.onCreate();
presenter.setState(toggle)
}
```

You can store this value as the global variable in the presenter and decide the app flow accordingly.